# How to copy the column headers of a data frame to each row value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to transform a pandas data frame, applying a function to all values, to concatenate the column header and the actual value.

My original dataframe is something like this:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|         Col1        |        Col2      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          12         |         34       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          12         |         34       |
```

The output should be:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|       Col1          |      Col2        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|       Col1_12       |      Col2_34     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|       Col1_12       |      Col2_34     |
```

What I tried is this:

```
mypandasdf.applymap(lambda x: 'columnname'+'_'+str(x))
```

But I'm struggling with the column name value. How can I put the real column name instead of a string?
Or is there any other/better way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC

```
df.apply(lambda x : x.name+'_'+x.astype(str))
Out[1323]: 
      Col1     Col2
0  Col1_12  Col2_34
1  Col1_12  Col2_34
```

Comment: what's the `.name`  here? is that the column names?

Comment: @Datanovice yes , that is columns name

Answer (score 3):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'colA': [12,34], 'colB': [56,78]})

df = df.columns.values + '_' + df.astype(str)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
      colA     colB
0  colA_12  colB_56
1  colA_34  colB_78
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `DataFrame.columns` to access each column and concatenate as string to each value:

```
for col in df.columns:
    df[col] = col + '_' + df[col].astype(str)
```

---

```
print(df)
      Col1     Col2
0  Col1_12  Col2_34
1  Col1_12  Col2_34
```

Answer (score 2):

Convert each row in your dataframe as string and concat the column name:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
                   "col1": [12 , 34],
                   'col2': [7,9]},)
for c in df:
    df[c] = c + '_' + df[c].astype(str)
df
```

Result:

```
    col1    col2
0   col1_12 col2_7
1   col1_34 col2_9
```

Comment: yup. 99% the same except "for c in df" rather than "in df.columns". When I copy/paste my answer, you're answer is still shown as "new answer"